# What does meta tag *~289 represent?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

I found the tag `*~289` on meta's questions page. What is it used for? Based on the count, it looks like a copy of the tag [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) but not sure if both the tags are same.

Clicking on the tag ***~289** just redirects me to meta's questions page with the following uri.  Note: The [tag page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/*~289).

[image: uri]

[image: Tag *~289]

Comment: it represents a bug :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We're unable to reproduce this, are you *sure* you saw what you *think* you saw?

It *could* be because the bug's gone, but we're going with *it's all in your head*.

For the record it's [@waffle's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/waffles) fault (he's on vacation, the wheel of blame need not be spun when we have an obvious victim), send him any hate mail (often, and late).

Comment: It's at least peculiar that the [tagged as *~289](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/*~289) page shows _all_ meta questions whereas a non-existing tag, [like wafflepower](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wafflepower) shows _zero_ questions

Comment: In fact, it appears that anything with a leading twiddle [~wafflepower](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/~wafflepower) redirects (without changing the URI) to the all questions page.

Comment: @Siva looks totally 'shopped to me - if you look carefully, the shadows are wrong.

Comment: @Siva - not sure if you're serious, but I was citing a meme: http://xkcd.com/331/