# Tag "*~294": what is it?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

I came across [this weird tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*~294) accidentally. SO claims there are 67488 questions tagged with it. Is it a bug or a feature?

The screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Seems to be gone now.

Comment: @TimPost Hm. I'm still seeing the thing on the Questions page in Related Tags.

Comment: I see 2,626,020 questions tagged...o.O

Comment: Another weird thing is that I cannot find the tag using search or filtering the Tags page.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100841/what-does-meta-tag-289-represent

Comment: @Costique Yup, but I'm not inclined to close this, as this seems to be one of _those_ bugs. Ya know, the kind that has been linked to [Tourette Syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tourette_syndrome).

Comment: @TimPost: [I'm seeing this in my list as well](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EEFEc.jpg)...

Comment: This is strange, I can't reproduce it.

Comment: @TimPost It's still there for me, though. Its number of questions is fluctuating as if it's a real thing.

Comment: Wait, [reproduced](http://stackoverflow.com/questions), look at the related tags between SQL and Ruby On Rails (thanks @Fabian)

Comment: @TimPost: I also notice that specific tag has a `title="show questions tagged '*~294'"` whereas all the other tags in that list have a `title=""`...

Comment: @TimPost Yay! That's it. I wonder if there's a valid tag which has the exact same number of questions. Could a valid tag be renamed/aliased?

Comment: Also found in the [Tagged Questions for c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), which shows `*~294` × 12836.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We had a secret sub-domain that we used to test features required for [facebook.stackoverflow.com](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com) and recently removed it.

This tag is just some stale data that will be purged in a few hours, after peak traffic.

Comment: And you would have gotten away with it, if it weren't for us *meddling kids!*

Comment: *shakes fist angrily*

Comment: Thanks for fixing it. Yeah, Facebook is evil, it's _that_ bad.

Answer (score 8):

I can't say why the tag was appearing in that list, but it seems to be a valid combination of wildcards. The `*` character is a client-side wildcard and `~` is a server side wildcard. The server-side wildcard has the additional restriction that you need at least 4 characters in your pattern or it will be rejected.

So what this tag pattern means is

```
*   :match anything client-side
~   :match anything server-side
294 :match 294
```

The last match is needed because of the server-side 4 character limit, if you remove the last character the pattern is rejected. If you use a number there that doesn't exist in any tag this part seems to be ignored entirely and you're left with a pattern that matches every question on the site.

For tag the [client-side wildcard is automatically replaced by the server-side wildcard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16615/151385), so this pattern is equivalent to `~~294`.

That this URL works is probably a feature, but this tag certainly shouldn't appear in any tag listings.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Looks like a bug. I wonder where the number comes from.