# *~289 tag revisited

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

A revisit of [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100841/220081).

The rogue `*~289` tag is back, and seems to come fleetingly. I have two screenshots - the first one from [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest) and the second [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug?sort=newest&pagesize=15)

[image]
[image]

The links might not work for everybody - as I said the bug comes seemingly randomly and have not found a way to consistent reproduce the bug.

---

**Edit:** the bug now seems more stable, but will still sometimes disappear.

Comment: "Sorry about the linking - the images seem to be quite big." Pssst, it's called a Retina display ;)

Comment: This is me - it will be resolved in a bit.  It's part of the facebook.stackoverflow.com removal.

Comment: FYI: this is being worked on - [it's just a fairly large set of changes](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XORpv.png) ...hold me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be resolved now - code changes stripping subsites and their magical tags has happened - we'll be watching for any side-effects for the next few days since that was a fairly large changeset.